# Working with Object Inside An Array

Tags: php

I have the following array, where i just want to get the value of type, and field for each entry, and echo them out. Not sure how to go about doing this with the shortest amount of code possible.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => id
            [Type] => int(11)
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => PRI
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => auto_increment
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => field2
            [Type] => varchar(64)
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => 
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $object){
  echo $object->Field . ': ' . $object->Type;
}
```

Comment: Any way to grab field without having to use $object->(insert x here)?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking, but I think you have to know the object's property name in order to echo it out or do something else with it.  There are ways to iterate through an object's properties: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php